# Is there any way I can sort the name of projects in Visual Studio in alphabetical order?

Tags: visual-studio

**I want project name BT10 to be placed under project name BT9**

[image]

Comment: They are sorted in alphabetical order. You want some combination of alphabetical and numerical order. Just prefixing your single digit numbers with zero is by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

the naming convention is ascending numeric values, so you may want to name your file as BT09, BT08